# How to solve logarithmic equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How to solve this logarithmic equation?

$$c_1\cdot n ^2 = c_2 \cdot n \cdot log_2 n$$

For now I'm stuck here:

$$n = \frac{c_2 \cdot log_2 n}{c_1}$$

How to proceed further? Is it possible to find $n$ ?

Comment: In general, there is no analytical way to solve transcendental equations such as the one you have posted. If you need to, you can solve for $n$ numerically, try [wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solutions are 
$$ n = -\dfrac{c_2 W(-c_1 \ln(2)/c_2)}{c_1 \ln(2)} $$
where $W$ is (a branch of) the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).

Comment: Did you forget a minus sign for the whole expression ?

Comment: You are very welcome !